# Implicits and type definitions

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to scala and struggling with the concept of implicits.

I have a class defined as following:

```
class SomeClass[A <: AA, B <: BB](val someParameter: String)
```

I'd like to use this class with other types not inheriting from AA and BB, like this:

```
val myInstanceOfSomeClass = SomeClass[C, D]
```

Knowing that C and D (which are Java classes, if that helps) can be converted to AA and BB instances thanks to their constructor

```
def myAInstance(someCValue : C) : A = new A(someCValue)
```

The value `myInstanceOfSomeClass` is used in another function as a parameter with the type SomeClass[C, D].

I know it's something related to implicit definitions but I'm quite lost with the syntax, especially where and how should I define the implicit definition...

So, how can I use my SomeClass with other types that can be converted to the defined types?

**EDIT**: *I cannot directly modify the definition of `SomeClass[A <: AA, B <: BB]` as it comes from an external library.*

Answer (score 2):

There's a related type bound called a "view bound" notated with `<%` that loosens the `<:` constraint by including literal subtypes as well as those for which an implicit conversion is available at the point of use.

So all you need to do is change your `SomeClass` to this:

```
class SomeClass[A <% AA, B <% BB](val someParameter: String)
```

… and, of course, make sure the *implicit* conversion is available where you want to use that class. This means you'll need the `implicit` keyword on the conversion:

```
implicit def myAInstance(someCValue : C) : A = new A(someCValue)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think it wasn't clear on my post but I can't change the definition of `class SomeClass[A <: AA, B <: BB](val someParameter: String)`. This is what I meant by saying "I'd like to use the class this way: `val myInstanceOfSomeClass = SomeClass[C, D]`. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Then you are out of luck and will have to explicitly apply the conversion (which then need not be an `implicit` of course).

Comment: Hmm... I thought I could make it somehow... Anyway, thanks! Should I accept your answer however?

Comment: Well, it's not really the answer you wanted, so I'd have to say no. Maybe a simple up-vote, if you're feeling generous.

Comment: I'd love to but I need 15 reputation points... but thanks anyway :)